# Linked server dynamic catalog for executing MDX through OpenQuery

Tags: sql-server-2008, mdx, linked-server, olap-cube, openquery

I have multiple OLAP databases in my project, so is it possible to dynamically decide the catalog for executing this MDX query?

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery(OLAP_SERVER, 'WITH MEMBER measures.X AS dimensions.count SELECT Measures.X ON 0 FROM MyCube') as X
```

I don't want to create a separate linked server for each of the OLAP database. 
Both the relational and cube databases reside on the same physical machine.

My linked server configuration are:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
@server = N'OLAP_SERVER'
, @srvproduct=N'OLAP_SERVER', @provider=N'MSOLAP'
, @datasrc=N'localhost'
--, @catalog=N'xxxx' default catalog commented out
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
@rmtsrvname = N'OLAP_SERVER'
, @locallogin = NULL 
, @useself = N'FALSE'
, @rmtuser=N'xxxx'
, @rmtpassword='xxxx'
GO
```

Alternatively, is it possible to fully qualify the cube name with the OLAP database name like [OLAPDBName].[MyCube] in the MDX script?

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `OpenRowset` instead of `OpenQuery`, you can specify the connection parameters dynamically as a string:

```
select *
from OpenRowset('MSOLAP', 
                'Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Provider=MSOLAP.4;Integrated Security=SSPI;Format=Tabular;',
'WITH MEMBER measures.X AS dimensions.count
 SELECT Measures.X ON 0 FROM MyCube')
```