# How can I change catalog in mdx query? Like "Use" in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, mdx, olap, openquery

Good day!

Can anybody tell me if there is an analog of "use" in mdx query? Or how can I change catalog context?

My task is to get data from olap using mdx query in OpenQuery. I can determine initial catalog on linked server, but there are several catalogs on OLAP server and I want to use one linked server to get access to all catalogs.

Comment: Have a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25712189/linked-server-dynamic-catalog-for-executing-mdx-through-openquery Maybe it has the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I should search more carefully in further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible with OpenQuery. You need to have separate linked servers for each catalog as `OpenQuery` executes the MDX only against the default catalog of the linked server.

If this is not feasible try using `OpenRowset` where you can specify string parameters to pass correct catalog information.

See information on `OpenRowSet` here 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/218592